# RxJava and facebook sdk threads trigger periodic cpu load in the background

Tags: android, facebook, rx-java, android-facebook, rx-android

I observed periodic cpu load after the app was *closed* with the home button. This load is caused by threads that are part of the facebook android sdk and RxJava.

---

Overview (trace for a period of 2 minutes after app is *closed* with the home button):

[image: Tracefile after app is closed (2 minutes)]

---

Facebook SDK active:

[image: facebook sdk active]

---

RxJava active:

[image: RxJava active]

I know that these threads are only active for < 1ms. However I have the feeling that waking up ever 15 seconds (facebook) / 70 seconds (RxJava) is bad for battery life. On average this leads to waking up every 10 seconds. The observed behavior also continues till the app is killed by the system.

**Is this behavior problematic and could reduce the battery life of the device or is this something that shouldn't cause any problems?**

Facebook:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this); // Application.onCreate
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, getString(R.string.app_id)); // Activity.onResume
AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this, getString(R.string.app_id)); // onPause
```

RxJava:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Versions:

- facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0
- rxjava:1.1.0
- rxandroid:1.1.0

Comment: Did you call `unsubscribe` when exiting?

Comment: zsxwing I just verified that it also happens within an empty test app that only has:
`sub = Observable.just(1l, 2l, 3l, 4l, 5l).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(...);` in `onResume` and `sub.unsubscribe();` in `onPause`

Comment: Schedulers.computation just doesn't shutdown the threads. But they should not be active as they don't have any work to do.

Comment: RxRingBuffer cleanup runs periodically on one of the computation schedulers in about 67 seconds apart.

Comment: The periodic work on the `RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor` seems to be caused [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/v1.1.1/src/main/java/rx/schedulers/CachedThreadScheduler.java#L36-L37). And I guess [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/fd2da397cfbf73a05f8c8715d18d11633c59d5bb/src/main/java/rx/internal/util/ObjectPool.java#L109-L128) is the part @akarnokd was talking about? However my question was regarding the topic whether this is a suitable behavior for a mobile application on Android

Comment: As you may know, this is now tracked as bug report in Facebook's issue tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/245480462469837/